# I can't get element by class

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am working with element like

```
<div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 9140px; left: 0px;" role="listbox">
```

when trying to start using Robot Framework for Python for creating autotests
I need to check this element exist, and, its items. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/148212), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: _"I can't get element by class"_ - why can't you? What have you tried, and what were the results?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
Page should contain element    css=div.slick-track
```

Or even better, in order to avoid possible delay issues (like an element taking a few seconds to be displayed on the page)

```
Wait until page contains element    css=div.slick-track
```

Comment: Didn't quite understand what you meant by "and, its items".

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question properly..

To locate the element by class:

```
Location should contain     class:slick-track
```

to check its attributes:

```
element attribute value should be      class:slick-track     role    listbox
```

let me know if this is what you meant.